# style input file button with JS - change text after file chosen

Tags: javascript, html, input, types, styles

I have an HTML input which I am hiding because I don't like to see "Choose a file".

http://jsfiddle.net/tPTxJ/

Codes:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('userFile').click(); return false;" />Upload Picture</a>

 <input type="file" id="userFile" name = "userFile" type="file" value="Snap Picture"  style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

I am trying to change my piece of text "Upload Picture" to "Picture Uploaded" once the picture file has been selected.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an id to your `<a>`

and do:

```
onchange=" document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = 'Picture Uploaded';"
```

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/tPTxJ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
document.getElementById('userFile').addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById('uploadLink').innerHTML = "Uploaded.";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an ["onchange"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange) handler to your file input element which changes the text of the anchor.

Comment: On change would work for colour but I need the text to change.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.  onchange will tell you when the file has been selected.  Then, you can use some simple javascript to change the text of the anchor.